# Provide base directory for import paths to Nose

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, nose

In my project, have a subdirectory containing a python application I'd like to unit-test.
The structure looks as follows:

```
my-project/
  python-app/
    sometool/
      __init__.py
      foo/
        __init__.py
        aaa.py
      bar/
        __init__.py
        bbb.py
    test/
      sometool-tests/
        foo-tests/
          aaa_test.py
```

Now, `aaa.py` contains imports like `import sometool.bar.bbb`, which assumes the application's base directory is `python-app`, which is indeed the case in my build setup.

`aaa_test.py` obviously imports `aaa` for testing it.
However, when running `nosetests ./python-app/sometool/test` from the main project directory, imports fail because `my-project` is now the base directory for imports, i.e. `sometool.bar.bbb` is not found from there.

If I `cd` into `python-app` first and run `nosetests ./sometool/test` from there, everything works as expected.
But I would like to configure Visual Studio Code to run those tests using a shortcut, and those command always seem to be executed from the project root.

Is there a way to pass the "base directory" as argument to Nose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a context providing module in the nosetests environment:

```
my-project/
  python-app/
     ...
  test/
    context.py
```

context.py:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

import python-app
```

Then you can import `python-app` in your tests import from the context module, e.g. in `aaa_test.py`:

```
from tests.context import python-app
from python-app.sometool import foo, bar
```

This should make nosetests always find the python app, no matter where it is being executed.

Comment: Thanks, this works! In order to not have to import `context` in all my test files, I ended up putting the path manipulation code into `__init__.py` (instead of `context.py`). Also, importing `python-app` seems not necessary that way.